# Interpreting HuggingFace's "siebert/sentiment-roberta-large-english" calculated score

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have not found any documentation either on HuggingFace's docsite, the github repo for this, or elsewhere that would explain this particular element of the subject model output.

I set up a basic pipeline to run:

```
# Set up the inference pipeline using a model from the  Hub
model_path = "siebert/sentiment-roberta-large-english"
berta_sentiment_analysis = pipeline("sentiment-analysis",model=model_path, tokenizer=model_path, max_length=512, truncation=True)
```

When passing a text string to the model, it returns a classification and also a score in the form of a dictionary.

```
{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9981653094291687}
```

Is the 'score' representative of accuracy (such as F1 score) or is it a polarity score (such as what nltk.sentiment.vader provides)? You can see [here](https://huggingface.co/siebert/sentiment-roberta-large-english) that the author(s) state that "For each instance, it predicts either positive (1) or negative (0) sentiment."  The documentation does not clearly state what score the model emits as part of the classification. It does not seem to be a polarity score but I'd like to be able to further explain the scoring.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are interested in this answer:  The `score` is calculated using the activation function after the final layer of the neural net (as per author/model creator).  It is used to determine polarity (and *is not a confidence score*).  The model returns an array with the score for each polarity, and the larger is the prediction.  The values will always be positive, regardless of the actual sentiment class tagged to the text.  This is unlike Vader's model which provides a composite polarity score that could be a positive or negative float based on the inferred sentiment (positive, negative, neutral).